# spring zuul print exception in ErrorController

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

When an exception thrown, finally it would be redirected to an error controller in `ErrorController`. But I could not find a way to print this exception.

```
@RestController
public class ErrorHandlerController implements ErrorController {

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String error() {
       // how to log this exception?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find exception in request attribute `javax.servlet.error.exception`. Zuul set exception object into request attribute like below.

```
request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception", exception);
```

So you can access this via HttpServletRequest object inside your controller.

Comment: when client sends a request to a non-exist url zuul redirects this to ErrorController without throwing any exception. We would like to print exceptions of such (not handled in any customized filters) in ErrorController. Because it is not handled in any filter, cannot call setAttribute method.